# _gaq.push not working in google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

ok, so, I have been trying to make _gaq.push work since so long now.

And my corresponding code is as below.

```js
var ext_id = localStorage.ext_id;
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-xx']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
//console.log(_gaq);
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js/ga.js'); //uncomment this
 //ga.src = "js/ga.js"
 // ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  document.head.append(ga); // make it head
 // var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); // comment this out
})();

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "google-analytics");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(response) {
      console.log("Message Passing with response",response.category,response.action, response);
     // _gaq.push(['_gat._forceSSL']); // remove  this
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', response.category, response.action,ext_id]); // trouble shoot this

      console.log(_gaq, "sending this");

  });
});
```

so, the above will be run when there's no activity on the payments page for more than 1 second. And its triggering properly, i.e its executing after 1 second of inactivity on payments page. But, but _gaq.push is showing no trace in the network tab, to make it more obscure, I'm not even getting any error. Can someone pls tell me what I could possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: ga.js is a legacy library. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

The gaq.push looks fine and should work.

I think your ga.js library is not loading. Maybe since getURL is deprecated? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL